# What is the difference between com.aventstack and com.relevantcodes dependencies of Extent Reports

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, report, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Following two dependencies can be used for intergrate Extent Reports into Maven Project.

```
<dependency>      
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>      
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>      
    <version>3.1.5</version> 
</dependency>

<dependency>      
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>      
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>      
    <version>2.41.2</version> 
</dependency>
```

What I need to know is what are the difference between these two Extent Report dependencies and when to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The package com.relevantcodes was used upto version 2 and com.aventstack is the package for version 3+.

Taken from extentreports.com/docs/versions/5/java/index.html